# What is Contoso and can i replace it for another thing?

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins, office-store

I'm developing an addin for excel and I want to know What is *Contoso* and if i can replace it for another thing.

In my manifest file i have this:

```
              <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
                <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
              </Icon>
```

For example, can i replace `<Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />` to `<Label resid="Anything.TaskpaneButton.Label" />`

Comment: Contoso is the name Microsoft gives the company in demo apps to demonstrate line of business applications. You should be able to replace it with your own company name.

Comment: I would like to add ... in context you have provided the `resid` is just the resource id which have to have corresponding resource id in the `Resources` section and may be anything you like. You don't need to use dotted notation or company name, etc. The following would be absolutely valid: `<Label resid="anything" />`, as long as `id="anything"` defined in the `Resources`.